# PTIJ: How does Hashem code with BYNH?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I'm writing an astrophysics emulator, and wanted to get as close to the original implementation as possible. The official history is [a bit vague](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), but it's a badly-kept secret (transcribed in ["Kel Adon"](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz,_Shabbat,_Shacharit,_Blessings_of_the_Shema,_First_Blessing_before_Shema.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that

> יְצָרָם בְּדַעַת בְּבִינָה וּבְהַשכֵּל. 
>   He fashioned [the luminaries] with DOS, BYNH, and Haskell.

I know what DOS and Haskell are (yes, you can [use them together](https://wiki.haskell.org/Implementations#Hugs)), but what is BYNH? I couldn't find it on GitHub.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Don’t forget that not longer after He finished creating the universe, there was a bit of a problem with some Python...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

בינה is not the name of the language, but rather a veiled description of it. (In this way, the secret is slightly less poorly-kept than you had surmised.)

As Rashi (among other Rishonim) explains, בינה is מבין דבר מתוך דבר, developing one thing out of another. So בינה refers to a language which is an incremental increase from a previous language.

So בינה is C++.

Comment: Check Rashi again; I think he's describing a compiler, not a language.

Answer (score 9):

BYNH is an acronym for "Bugs You; Not Hashem"

In other words, inevitably, all computer programs have bugs, and operating systems such as DOS are notorious for having them. But these bugs are all because we're human, and we make mistakes or bugs in the programming.

Hashem, however, never makes mistakes, because He is perfect and writes perfect everlasting code. This is a unique computer language only for G-d.

This explains exactly what the prayer means by saying that G-d fashioned the luminaries with BYNH. The sun and moon have no imperfections and their orbits are perfect and continuously reliable. Of course! Because G-d used the BYNH language to program them that way. If only Microsoft could get in on this secret.

Answer (score 5):

We know from the holy ספר אקסקסידי that [the universe was created with Perl](//xkcd.com/224). What it doesn't tell us is *which* Perl was used. The poem you cite clarifies: בבינה. The universe was created using the work of [Bina Perl, evolutionary biologist](http://www.mvences.de/p/p1/Vences_A351.pdf). This proves that the animals of the world were created using evolution.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55823

Answer (score 3):

בינה is actually short for [BeanShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeanShell), which is a Java-like programming language.

Answer (score 2):

בינה is actually the genetic code in גבב"א transcription (with two minor transcription errors).  גבב"א is a simple ROT-21 cipher (ב to א ;ג becomes ב; and ד to ג...).

If you the reverse (an אבב"ג transformation) to decode בינה, you get גכסו.

- ג: G (guanine)
- כ: C (cytosine)
- ס: T (thymine) -- this was a simple transcription error before the cipher: a thav became a samech
- ו: A (adenine) -- this was a transcription error AFTER the cipher.  Ciphertext ת became ה.

So the proper ciphertext should be בישת.

יְצָרָם בְּדַעַת **בישת** וּבְהַשכֵּל.

And G-d made them in DOS shell, using nucleobases, and in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

After some reflection, I think [Y ez](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89683/1852) and [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/ptij-how-does-hashem-code-with-bynh/89683#comment290188_89683) are closest to the mark.

If בינה  meant just that a compiler was used, or that the programming language was C++, it could have just said so. So the use of בינה lets us *darshan* it twice - that it is a compiler *written* in C++.

When you think about it, this makes sense. We know that the world is built on the Torah (הסתכל באורייתא וברא עלמא), and the Torah itself couldn't be written in Haskell, because the Torah is imperative (תורה **צוה** לנו), not declarative.

Comment: The Torah may be a multi-paradigm language.  As you know G-d *declares* that various aspects of creation are good.  However, as you also probably know, every declarative language is actually elaborate syntactic sugar around a simpler imperative language. What might that be?